# Checking a radio button within asp.net application

Tags: html, asp.net, css, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have this code:

```
<div class="divpere" >
   <div class="divfille1" ><label>CIVILITE:</label></div>
      <div class="divfille2" >
         <input type="radio" ID="mademoiselle" runat="server" >Mademoiselle</input>
         <input type="radio" ID="madame" runat="server">Madame</input>
         <input type="radio" ID="monsieur" runat="server">Monsieur</input>
      </div>
   </div>
```

It's a labale and a list of radio buttons, when i try to check one of this radio button, it still not checked!!

- What is the reason of this?
- How can i fix my  snippet?

Comment: I'll bet on a css issue. Would be good if you post your css or better make a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YhqK/1/)

```
 <div class="divpere" >
        <div class="divfille1" ><label>CIVILITE:</label></div>
        <div class="divfille2" >
         <input name="samename" type="radio" id="mademoiselle" runat="server" /><label for="mademoiselle"> Mademoiselle</label>
         <input name="samename" type="radio" id="madame" runat="server"/><label for="madame">Madame</label>
         <input name="samename" type="radio" id="monsieur" runat="server"/><label for="monsieur">Monsieur</label>
        </div>
 </div>
```

You should mention the `name attribute` for your radio buttons and Don't forget to mention the same name values for all three radio buttons...

Comment: I have the same result even i add `name` attribute